# Laravel query builder General error 2031

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

Below is my query using Laravel query builder:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-07-01');
$end = new DateTime('2016-07-31');
$startDate = $begin->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$endDate = $end->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
$deposit = $depositModel->select(DB::raw('user_deposit.user_id as user_id, sum(user_deposit.amount) as total_deposit, null as total_withdraw'))
                        ->whereBetween('date_time', [$startDate, $endDate])
                        ->where('user_deposit.status', 1)
                        ->groupBy('user_deposit.user_id');
$withdraw = $withdrawModel->select(DB::raw('user_withdraw.user_id as user_id, null as total_deposit, sum(user_withdraw.amount) as total_withdraw'))
                        ->whereBetween('user_withdraw.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
                        ->where('user_withdraw.status', 1)
                        ->groupBy('user_withdraw.user_id');
$deposit = $deposit->unionAll($withdraw);
$transaction = DB::table(DB::raw("({$deposit->toSql()}) t"))
                  ->select('user_id', DB::raw("sum(total_deposit) as total_deposit_amount, sum(total_withdraw) as total_withdraw_amount"))
                  ->groupBy('user_id')
                  ->get();
```

I was hoping to get the outcome like below:

```
"transaction": [
            {
                "user_id": 2,
                "total_deposit_amount": "101.00",
                "total_withdraw_amount": "50.50"
            },
            {
                "user_id": 5,
                "total_deposit_amount": null,
                "total_withdraw_amount": "50.50"
            }
        ]
```

But then I keep getting **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031**. So I used **toSql()** on the query to get the raw sql query and tried to run it in MySQL and it generated the expected result as above.

Below is the query after running toSql()

```
SELECT`user_id`, SUM(total_deposit) AS total_deposit_amount, SUM(total_withdraw) AS total_withdraw_amount 
FROM (( SELECT user_deposit.user_id AS user_id, SUM(user_deposit.amount) AS total_deposit, null AS total_withdraw 
        FROM `user_deposit` 
        WHERE`date_time` BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-31' 
        AND `user_deposit`.`status` = 1 
        GROUP BY `user_deposit`.`user_id`) 
        UNION ALL (SELECT user_withdraw.user_id AS user_id, null AS total_deposit, SUM(user_withdraw.amount) AS total_withdraw 
                   FROM `user_withdraw` 
                   WHERE `user_withdraw`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-31' 
                   AND `user_withdraw`.`status` = 1
                   GROUP BY `user_withdraw`.`user_id`)) t 
        GROUP BY `user_id`
```

So the question is, what's wrong with my query builder? Why does raw sql works while query builder doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you post the original code the one that does not involve raw instead

Comment: @e4c5 already updated it

Comment: I am a bit confused clearly your laravel code is using raw but you have said the raw query works. So what is it tht doesn't work??

Comment: @e4c5 the Laravel code is giving me error, while the raw sql below is returning me result. i know the laravel code is exactly like the raw sql that's why i have no idea why it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After much research, it seems like I have missed out this

```
mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
```

My code:

```
$transaction = DB::table(DB::raw("({$deposit->toSql()}) t"))
                  ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())  // this is required for selecting from subqueries
                  ->select('user_id', DB::raw("sum(total_deposit) as total_deposit_amount, sum(total_withdraw) as total_withdraw_amount"))
                  ->groupBy('user_id')
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! saved my time thanks to your research!
In my case I have a subquery with its own bindings.