# How to join tables resulting from subqueries in Laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-query-builder, laravel-4.2

I have created a query in mysql that uses a subquery. I have tried to reproduce this query in Laravel 4.2 like this:

```
$store_booklets = DB::table('booklets')
                            ->select(
                                'booklets.id',
                                'booklets.title',
                                'booklets.start_date',
                                'booklets.end_date'
                            )
                            ->join('booklet_store', function ($join) use ($storeId) {
                                $join->on('booklets.id', '=', 'booklet_store.booklet_id')
                                     ->where('booklet_store.store_id', '=', $storeId);
                            })
                            ->whereRaw('booklets.active = 1')
                            ->whereRaw('booklets.start_date < curdate()')
                            ->whereRaw('booklets.end_date > curdate()');


$store_booklets_products = DB::table('booklet_product')
                             ->select('*')
                             ->join(DB::raw("({$store_booklets->toSql()}) as store_booklets"), function ($join) {
                                 $join->on('booklet_product.booklet_id', '=', 'store_booklets.id');
                             });
```

When I do `$store_booklets_products->get()` it gives me a

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Although, if I do `$store_booklets_products->toSql()` it outputs the correct sql query.

I can't figure out what is wrong with query. I had a similar problem in Laravel 5 before that had to do with the use of the method `where` inside the subquery I solved it by using `whereRaw` instead. But that doesn't seem to work in Laravel 
4.2.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732587/laravel-query-builder-general-error-2031) question is referred that one should use the method `mergeBindings($subqueryQueryBuilder)` when selecting from a table resulting from a subquery and I tried this

```
$store_booklets_products = DB::table('booklet_product')
                                    ->mergeBindings($store_booklets)
                                    ->select('*')
                                    ->join(DB::raw("({$store_booklets->toSql()}) as store_booklets"), function ($join) {
                                        $join->on('booklet_product.booklet_id', '=', 'store_booklets.id');
                                    });
```

but in my case the error persists.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was indeed related to the bindings of the query builder. Since I was passing the variable `$storeId` to the subquery, when assembling the query I had to add the method `addBinding` passing to it the `$storeId`, like this:

```
$store_booklets_products = DB::table('booklet_product')
                                    ->select('*')
                                    ->join(DB::raw("({$store_booklets->toSql()}) as store_booklets"), function ($join) {
                                        $join->on('booklet_product.booklet_id', '=', 'store_booklets.id');
                                    })
                                    ->addBinding($storeId);
```

According to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-you-add-a-binding-when-using-dbraw-in-a-join) the class `Grammar` resets the bindings during the compilation hence the need to reattach it.